# Typescript Filter Array of Objects by Duplicate Properties

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array of objects I would like to filter to return objects with duplicate property values.

My Array of Objects:

```
values = [
  { id: 1, name: 'a' },
  { id: 2, name: 'b' },
  { id: 3, name: 'c' },
  { id: 4, name: 'a' }
];
```

The result I would like to have in a new array of objects:

```
duplicateValues = [
  { id: 1, name: 'a' },
  { id: 4, name: 'a' }
];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Group the values by their `name` using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://www.google.com/search?q=reduce+js&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIN914IN914&oq=reduce&aqs=chrome.1.69i59l3j0i433i512l2j0i67j0i67i433j69i60.1595j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
- Filter the groups where the length is greater than `1` using [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- And finally flatten the resultant array using [Array.prototype.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

```js
const values = [{ id: 1, name: "a" }, { id: 2, name: "b" }, { id: 3, name: "c" }, { id: 4, name: "a" }];

const duplicates = Object.values(
  values.reduce((r, v) => ((r[v.name] ??= []).push(v), r), {})
)
  .filter((g) => g.length > 1)
  .flat();

console.log(duplicates);
```

**TypeScript solution:**

```
type Values = { id: number, name: string }[];

const values = [{ id: 1, name: "a" }, { id: 2, name: "b" }, { id: 3, name: "c" }, { id: 4, name: "a" }];

const duplicates = Object.values(
  values.reduce(
    (r: { [k: string]: Values }, v) => ((r[v.name] ??= []).push(v), r),
    {}
  )
)
  .filter((g) => g.length > 1)
  .flat();

console.log(duplicates);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    function findDuplicates(data) {
      // map containing already added names.
      const existing = new Map();
      // set containing names, which were parsed in passed and added at future occurence of that name
      const consideredReadd = new Set();
      // final output array
      const output = [];
      data.forEach((item) => {
         if(!existing.has(item.name)) {
              // if not present in already parsed names, add in map
              existing.set(item.name, item);
         } else {
              if (!consideredReadd.has(item.name)) {
                  // if is already present and past record isn't added in output array, add that record in output array and set the key in data set.
                  consideredReadd.add(item.name);
                  output.push(existing.get(item.name));
              }
              // push the current item as it existed in past
              output.push(item);
         }
      });
      // return output array
      return output;
    }


    let values = [
      { id: 1, name: 'a' },
      { id: 2, name: 'b' },
      { id: 3, name: 'c' },
      { id: 4, name: 'a' }
    ];
    
    duplicateValues = findDuplicates(values);
    
    console.log(duplicateValues);
```

Comment: this does not work and just outputs an empty array https://tsplay.dev/WoGEgW

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: Another point: code-only answers are of very limited help.  Could you add some explanation for the OP?

Comment: @ScottSauyet added comments.

Comment: Upvoting because you're willing to put additional effort in, but usually it's best to have explanatory text outside the code altogether, explaining not only how the code works but something about the choices made.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the array and filter them based on value. See the demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-xww2ai?file=index.ts

```js
const values = [
  { id: 1, name: 'a' },
  { id: 2, name: 'b' },
  { id: 3, name: 'c' },
  { id: 4, name: 'a' },
];

const copyValues = [...values];

const duplicateObjects = values.filter(
  (v) => copyValues.filter((cp) => cp.name === v.name).length > 1
);
console.log(duplicateObjects);
```

Comment: How could I do this with excluding null values for the name property?

Comment: Note that this has higher algorithmic complexity (`O (n ^ 2)`) than the answers from SSM and Aakash Garg (`O (n)`).  This may or may not be a problem, but it's always worth noting.

Comment: even SSM answer have higher complexity. as filtering flatterning reducing all reiterates array. which isn't required in this case.

Comment: @AakashGarg: `O (3n)` is the same algorithmic complexity as `O (n)`.  Your answer and that one make different tradeoffs -- you have many more `if` tests, for instance -- and without testing I have no idea which would be faster for what size inputs.  And if the expected input is small enough, performance may not matter at all.  The big difference between this answer and the other two is how well it would theoretically scale.